# Can't find X-Frame-Options in Tomcat 8.0.12

Tags: tomcat

I have Tomcat 8.0.12 installed on a Centos 7 server and I am trying to set the "X-Frame-Options" to tighten security. I do not see it in web.xml or server.xml. Is there somewhere else to set it? Does 8.0.12 not support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [HTTP Header Security Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter) but this wasn't introduced until 8.0.23.

Further, Tomcat 8.0.x reached [end of life](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html) over a year ago and is no longer supported. You should upgrade to 8.5.x or, better still, 9.0.x.

When you have a Tomcat version that supports the HTTP Header Security Filter you can configure it in your web application's web.xml.

Comment: That is what I thought I might have to do.

Thanks for the response!